# Can't change kafka broker-id in Incubator Helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, google-kubernetes-engine, apache-zookeeper, kubernetes-helm

I have one Zookeeper server (say `xx.xx.xx.xxx:2181`) running on one GCP Compute Instance VM separately.

I have 3 GKE clusters all in different regions on which I am trying to install Kafka broker nodes so that all nodes connect to one Zookeeper server(`xx.xx.xx.xxx:2181`).

I installed the Zookeeper server on the VM following [this guide](https://codeforgeek.com/how-to-setup-zookeeper-cluster-for-kafka/) with zookeeper properties looking like below:

```
dataDir=/tmp/data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=0
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
tickTime=2000

# list of servers
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
```

I am using this [Incubator Helm Chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/kafka) to deploy the brokers on GKE clusters.

As per the [README.md](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/kafka#installing-the-chart) I am trying to install with the below command:

```
helm repo add incubator http://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-charts-incubator

helm install --name my-kafka \
  --set replicas=1,zookeeper.enabled=false,configurationOverrides."broker\.id"=1,configurationOverrides."zookeeper\.connect"="xx.xx.xx.xxx:2181" \
  incubator/kafka
```

#### Error

When I deploy using any of the above ways described above on all of the three GKE Clusters, only one of the brokers gets connected to the Zookeeper server and the other two pods just restart infinitely.

When I check the Zookeeper log (on the VM), it looks something like below:

```
...
[2019-10-30 14:32:30,930] INFO Accepted socket connection from /xx.xx.xx.xxx:54978 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2019-10-30 14:32:30,936] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /xx.xx.xx.xxx:54978 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-10-30 14:32:30,938] INFO Established session 0x100009621af0057 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /xx.xx.xx.xxx:54978 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-10-30 14:32:32,335] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100009621af0057 type:create cxid:0xc zxid:0x422 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/users Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /config/users (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-10-30 14:32:34,472] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100009621af0057 type:create cxid:0x14 zxid:0x424 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/ids/0 Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/ids/0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-10-30 14:32:35,126] INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x100009621af0057 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-10-30 14:32:35,127] INFO Closed socket connection for client /xx.xx.xx.xxx:54978 which had sessionid 0x100009621af0057 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2019-10-30 14:36:49,123] INFO Expiring session 0x100009621af003b, timeout of 6000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
...
```

I am sure I have created firewall rules to open necessary ports and that is not a problem because one of the broker nodes is able to connect (the one who reaches first).

To me, this seems like the `borkerID` are not getting changed for some reason and that is the reason why Zookeeper is rejecting the connections.
I say this because `kubectl logs pod/my-kafka-n` outputs something like below:

```
...
[2019-10-30 19:56:24,614] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Shutdown completed (kafka.network.SocketServer)
...
[2019-10-30 19:56:24,627] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
...
```

As we can see above says `brokerId=0` for all of the pods in all the 3 clusters.

However, when I do `kubectl exec -ti pod/my-kafka-n -- env | grep BROKER`, I can see the environment variable `KAFKA_BROKER_ID` is changed to `1`, `2` and `3` for different brokers as I set.

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to change the kafka-broker id or to make all brokers connect to one Zookeeper instance?

Comment: Where are you seeing in the instructions or chart variables that the broker ID is overridable? Even if you tried to set it that would attempt to set the same value for each broker. Also, single Kubernetes nor Kafka clusters should stretch regions... Do you mean availability zones?

Comment: `configurationOverrides` variable has a default value of `{ "confluent.support.metricsenable": false }` as we can see in the configurable parameters and the variable has description like **Kafka [configuration setting](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) overrides in the dictionary format**. Clicking on the "configuration settings" takes us to the kafka broker configuration page which has both `zookeepeer.connect` and `broker.id`.

Comment: Stretching regions is a requirement. Zones would have been really simple, I understand it is matter of using multi-zonal GKE cluster. 

Comment: About changing broker ids, most important thing in my assumption is, when we increase the pod replica to 2 or more, all of the brokers get connected to one single zookeeper. So somehow this implies that the brokerid is getting changed, right? am I getting all this correct?

Comment: Broker IDs should not be auto-generated. The ought to be manually assigned, and they must remain with the same pod at all times across restarts and scaling. And you're likely going to run into a lot of latency issues with a streched cluster. Zookeeper would also lose quorum fairly reguarly without proper tuning.

Comment: I understand about the latency, that is fine. What do you mean by *"Broker IDs should not be auto-generated"*? When we increase the pod replica to be more than one, somehow the helm chart auto-generates the Broker ID right? It stays with the pod always then too. Plus, I am assigning the broker IDs manually as well, I am giving the value `1`,`2` and `3` manually in the command line while deploying the broker. I am sorry for the confusion, but I did not get your point here.

Comment: 1) In the docs, `If unset, a unique broker id will be generated` 2) [The broker id is set by the pod name](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/incubator/kafka/templates/statefulset.yaml#L192-L201), you should not set it externally, otherwise. 3) I have no experience with Kafka on k8s, but I would look at using Strimzi rather than the incubator charts first

Comment: You're a godsend. So basically, this helm chart doesn't allow changing the broker ID. I will take the ID starting with `0` to `n` (`n` being the replications of the stateful sets). As stateful sets have an integer value at the end of there names, this Helm chart uses that integer to give the Broker id. I manually exported the BrokerID in the `statefulset.yaml` file and all three nodes were able to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> make all brokers connect to one Zookeeper instance?

Seems like you are doing that okay via the `configurationOverrides` option. That'll deploy all pods with the same configuration.

That being said, the broker ID should not be the same per pod. If you inspect the statefulset YAML, it appears that [the broker ID is calculated based on the `POD_NAME` variable](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/incubator/kafka/templates/statefulset.yaml#L192-L201)

---

<sub>Sidenote</sub>

> 3 GKE clusters all in different regions on which I am trying to install Kafka broker nodes so that all nodes connect to one Zookeeper server

It's not clear to me how you would able to deploy to 3 sepearate clusters in one API call. But, this architecture isn't recommended by Kafka, Zookeeper, or Kubernetes communities unless these regions are "geographically close"